# Communication link failure error in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have been trying to connect a database to my spring boot application but it didn't work out and give me an error. So, if anyone could give me a hint about what should I do?
I have tried to remove and add dependencies in pom.XML but nothing solved the issue

Backstory: I am trying to do a college project that is a web-service for an online store platform but this is my only error if the database connection succeeded I think there will be no other errors. I see an answer for another question have the same problem but non of the answers solved my problem

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.onlinemarket.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar:8.0.19]
    ... 52 common frames omitted

2020-04-02 03:28:54.730  WARN 5764 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2020-04-02 03:28:54.733  WARN 5764 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2020-04-02 03:28:54.744  INFO 5764 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-02 03:28:54.765  INFO 5764 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-04-02 03:28:54.767 ERROR 5764 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.onlinemarket.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.8.Final.jar:5.4.8.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

and that is my connection properties

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3360/onlinemarket
    username: root
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
```

Comment: make sure your database is up and running. Also, you can debug by setting ->  level: 
 org.hibernate: DEBUG  in application.yml

Comment: Do you have all the dependencies in the pom.xml @Youssef Hassan

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have proper dependencies in pom.xml like spring data jpa and mysql connector.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Your application.yml should looks like below. You have to add hibernate dialect.

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3360/onlinemarket
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 
jpa:
    properties:
        hibernate:
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
            ddl-auto: update
            format_sql: true
            show_sql: true
```

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: try to add driver also 
**driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**.
If not try mysql Cj driver **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**. I updated the answer also

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern. I delete the schema and let the application to create it and it worked.